# check if java process is running and re-run if it is not running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

On ubuntu 15.04, I am running java app through vnc sessions.  I have 8 defined sessions that are started during system boot.  My question is, how do I create a script that checks to see if the process is still running on the various vnc displays (say :1 to :8) and re-start the java process if I detect a given vnc session is not running?

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted at Unix+Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244247/check-if-java-process-is-running-and-re-run-if-it-is-not-running

Comment: Cross-posted at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244247/check-if-java-process-is-running-and-re-run-if-it-is-not-running .

Comment: can you show some of your attempts? The goal is to help debug/troubleshoot, not to do the work for others here.